# Roundcube Layout Default

Tags: webmail

I'm trying to migrate clients from an old version of Roundcube to a recent release, but it seems that a number of defaults have changed (I suspect in Roundcube 1.3)

One of these is that Roundcube appears to default to a 3 column layout for email - although it is possible to set it to a 2 column layout on a per user basis once logged in to Roundcube.   Looking at the webpage where I can change the layout, the form field has a name "_layout" - with a desired value of 'desktop' , but this does not appear to correspond to anything I can see in the config file, and setting $config['layout'] and $config['_layout'] don't appear to do anything.

**Is there a global setting I can add/change (eg in config.inc.php or defaults.inc.php) that will let me specify a 2 column layout by default?**